# Are British curd, Cottage Cheese, Indian Chena the same thing?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

Are these the same thing ?

- British Curd - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd
- Cottage Cheese - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottage_cheese
- Indian Chena - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhena

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

'Curd' is the generic name for the solids obtained from coagulating milk.

Cottage cheese is a type of curd cheese that is unpressed, and not entirely removed of whey, so it stays creamy and wet, with soft lumps

Chhena is a curd cheese that is strained to (almost) completely remove the whey, and gently pressed to firm it up and form a more coherent mass of curd

Answer (score -2):

There is no way you could call indian chhena a curd.

Recipes (taken from my mom):

*Curd*: Take lukewarm milk and add curd. Cover with a lid (most important step). Wait for 4-5 hrs.

*Chhena*: Heat 1/2 L milk and keep the flame on. Squeeze 1 full lemon in it. Keep stirring until the white part is completely separated from near transparent liquid. Filter!

Comment: To clarify: this question was about the word "curd" as used in British English, which is a class of cheeses. The word "curd" in Indian English is used for something else, namely for yogurt. It is just one of those false friends, like "pants" in British and American English.

Comment: There is a reason I explicily mentioned 'British' curd, which was to avoid confusion with 'Indian curd'... 
British curd = a type of homemade cheese;
Indian curd = homemade yogurt